# Is there a limitation to length of job name in AutoSys R11

Tags: autosys

Is there a limitation to length of job name in AutoSys R11. I am aware of limitation of 64 chars in normal autosys instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, R11.3 has the same limitation.

Unfortunately I can not provide a link to the online documentation, but I have PDF file called "CA Workload Automation AE. Reference Guide. r11.3, Third Edition" which contains following info:

> **`insert_job` Subcommand — Add a Job to the Database**
>
> The `insert_job` subcommand adds a job definition to the database. Depending on the type of job you are adding, the `insert_job` subcommand requires one or more additional attributes.
>
> **Note:** You must define the machine using the `insert_machine` command before you can insert a job that uses that machine. The job will not insert if the machine definition does not exist.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> This subcommand has the following format:

```
insert_job: job_name
```

> `job_name` Defines the name of the job that you want to schedule.
>
> **Limits: Up to 64 characters**; valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, period (.), underscore (_), hyphen (-), and pound (#); do not include embedded spaces or tabs

Comment: I did explored more & found from one of firm's internal documentation & tried inserting as well ( it continues with behavior of truncating exceeding characters from job name). May be this is the link which you tried adding : http://support.ca.com/phpdocs/0/common/impcd/r11/Catalyst/ITPAM_Connectors/CA_Workload_Automation_AE_Connector_ENU.pdf